# Is there a quantum algorithm to find the xor of a dataset

Tags: quantum-algorithms

Given a black box function f taking an input of length n bits, is there a quantum algorithm which can find the xor of all possible outputs of f, in less than 2^n calls to f?

Comment: Does $f$ produce 1-bit output?

Comment: No. It produces output of constant length

Comment: Although I'm still interested if there is a solution for 1 bit output.

Comment: For 1 bit output use quantum counting, and then take the solution mod 2

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the output is of subexponential length, this can be done using quantum counting.

First use an adaptation of Grover's algorithm to find the input with the maximum length output as described [here](https://hiqsimulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/examples.Intro_Maximum_Search.html). You then know the total number of output bits you need to find.

Then for each output bit, use quantum counting to count the number of inputs which have 1 as the entry for that bit, and hence find the xor for that bit.